# SSMS: Error message returned when connecting to local server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can I have some help please?  I've spent around 3-4 hours trying some of the other solutions on this site and looking at u-Tube but am unable to understand a problem I am having logging into SQL Server.

Briefly: October 2017 downloaded 2016 Express edition SSMS. Used for 3-4 months without issue. Server Name = (Name of local machine), Authentication = Windows Authentication, User Name = (Name of local machine\my name). I'm using Windows 10 (might have updated to this since originally downloading SSMS????)

Didn't log into SSMS for around 3 months but when I did I received an error message;
"A network related or instance specific error occurred whilst establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error : 40 - could not open a connection to SQL Server)(Microsoft SQL Server error 2).

Shortly after I uninstalled SSMS 2016 and today (27.12.2017) installed 2017. The installation was fine but I get the same error message when attempting to connect to my local machine.

I have tried many of the other solutions posted for this error. The most common seem to involve:

1. Opening SQL Services Configuration Manager, SQL Server Services and restarting SQL Server. When I open the Configuration Manager and highlight SQL Server Services there are no services running.
2. Restarting a Service directly from the Services Window. Again I have no SQL Server services showing.
3. One site suggested looking at the 'Logs' where it was possible to identify that the trial period for SSMS had expired.  When I looked at the logs on this machine there was no record of any SQL Logs. Besides, as I downloaded SSMS 2017 today this would be irrelevant.

(Apologies for lack of screen prints - I'm not yet authorised to upload any apparently).

Can someone point me in the right direction please? If I've not supplied enough information please let me know what else is required and I'll happily supply it.

Many thanks
Dave Morgan

Comment: Are you saying that you have no SQL Server services installed on your local computer? You won't be able to connect to that which does not exist. SSMS is only a client for SQL Server and there is no license expiration for it. It sounds like you just don't have SQL Server installed on your computer.

Comment: Thanks alroc.  I previously uninstalled SSMS 2016. Do I need to reinstall this version?  Today I downloaded and installed V17.4 from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms.  
Re reading the notes it says "The SSMS 17.x installation does not upgrade or replace SSMS versions 16.x or earlier. SSMS 17.x installs side by side with previous versions so both versions are available for use. .."  Does this mean I cannot just have a 17.x installation on my machine? Many thanks

Comment: SSMS is not your problem - you need to install SQL Server itself, or connect to an existing installation of it on another computer. They are two separate pieces of software.

Comment: Thanks alroc - solved.  Didn't realise I'd uninstalled SQL Server as well as SSMS.  Really appreciate your help. Dave